# React input value is not getting updated although value next to it with same variable is

Tags: reactjs

Basically I use a react input and can't get it's textvalue to update when I click on a button but the value right next to it gets updated on a re-render. I'm also using Redux to call a service to update the values.

So for example if the input quantity loads up with value 55 and I click the '+' button I'd expect the input quantity to get updated to 56 and the value right next to it to be 56. (the value right next to it is there for debug purposes). What actually happens is that the input value stays at 55 and the value right next to it gets updated to 56. Any idea what the problem is?

I have the following code:

```
class GroceryItemEditModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.handleQuantityChange = this.handleQuantityChange.bind(this);
    this.handleQuantityBlur = this.handleQuantityBlur.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.refreshEditItemData === true) {
      this.props.loadEditItem(this.props.selectedEditItem.Id);
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.selectedEditItem) {
      this.props.loadEditItem(this.props.selectedEditItem.Id);
    }
  }
  addItem() {
    const quantity = this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity + 1;

    this.props.setEditItemQuantity(this.props.selectedEditItem.Id, quantity);
  }
  removeItem() {
    const quantity = this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity - 1;

    this.props.setEditItemQuantity(this.props.selectedEditItem.Id, quantity);
  }
  handleQuantityBlur(event) {
    const quantity = event.target.value;

    this.props.setEditItemQuantity(this.props.selectedEditItem.Id, quantity);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.props.toggleEditItemVisibility(!this.props.showEditItem);
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.props.selectedEditItem) {
      return <div />;
    }
    let spinner = '';
    if (this.props.modifyingEditItem) {
      spinner = <FontAwesome name="spinner" spin />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.showEditItem} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Edit Grocery Item</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div>{this.props.selectedEditItem.Name}</div>
            <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="blah">Quantity</Label>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="1">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.removeItem}>-</Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="9">
                    <Input name="selectedItemQty" id="selectedItemQty" Value={this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity} onBlur={this.handleQuantityBlur}></Input>{this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity}
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="1">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addItem}>+</Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="1">
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
            {spinner}
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Close</Button>{' '}
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is the prop **Value** in the component **Input** well spelled ?

```
<Input
  name="selectedItemQty"
  id="selectedItemQty"
  /*the V is capitalized is that normal ?*/Value={this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity}
  onBlur={this.handleQuantityBlur}>
</Input>
{this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity}
```

Comment: That was it. Silly error thanks. Oh but wait. Now I can't update the value manually. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: you have to add an onChange event to your input and update your redux state, you probably need a new action exp: setInputChange that will update selectedEditItem value on the state.

Comment: Have you actually tried it. I think because I put value={this.props.selectedEditItem.Quantity} the prop actually has to be that value so in my case I actually have to call the service to update this value. If I do that then there seems to be a delay with that value being updated on the screen. So for example if I have a quantity of 5 and I change it to 6 then for a split second it stays 5 until I update it on the service and refresh the value because when I refresh the value then and only then the state is updated..

Comment: Yes I've tried it @Mok, just do as i told you and it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following thing:

Use an attribute "key" on Input component and give it a random id whenever Input component renders... like this:

< Input key={shordid.generate()}        .... whatever props... .>